# Does there exists a $k$-critical graph having connectivity $2$ for every $k\geq 3$?

Tags: graph-theory

Does there exists a $k$-critical graph having connectivity $2$ for every $k\geq 3$?

I know the answer should be yes, because for every $k$-critical graph $G$ with $k \geq 3$ then $G$ must be $2$-connected and $k-1$ edge-connected.

My first thought is $K_k$ but this is not $2$-connected. Should I delete something from $K_k$?

Comment: Note that by definition, $K_k$ is $2$-connected for any $k > 2.$

Comment: @Jernej Think only $2$-connected, else it ain't fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only for $k=3$, the example being any odd cycle; and no for $k > 3$.

For proving the non-existence of such graphs for $k > 3$, we need the following theorem.

**Theorem 12.24 (Harary's Graph Theory p. 141)**
*No critical graph can be separated by a complete subgraph.*

**Proof:** To prove this assume that a clique induced on $S$ of size $n$ does separate a critical graph, with $\chi=k$ into components $C_i$. Then each of subgraphs induced by $V(C_i)\cup S$ will have chromatic number less than $k$. Consider such a subgraph induced by $V(C_j)\cup S$ with the maximum chromatic number say $k_1$ (which is still $< k$). For the rest components $C_i$ we can change the colorings accordingly to give a $k_1$-coloring to the whole graph, which is a contradiction. $\square$

This implies if our $k$-critical graph has connectivity exactly two i.e. removal of two vertices disconnects the graph, then these two vertices say $u$ and $v$ are not adjacent.

*Another important property of a $k$-critical graph is that for every vertex $w$ there is a $k$-coloring such that the color on $w$ appears nowhere else, and the other $k-1$ colors appear on $N(w)$.*

Now consider the $k$-coloring in which $u$ is the only vertex with color say $1$ and $v$ has color $2$. Since $N(u)$ has $k-1$ colors, there has to be at least another vertex with color $2$. Also, since $N(v)$ doesn't contain color $1$ (since color $1$ is uniquely assigned to $u$ and $u \nsim v$), $v$ can have the color $1$; hence it can be deleted without reducing the chromatic number. Hence we have a contradiction.

Comment: so your answer is it must be $K_k$?

Comment: For only 2-connected; and for k>3 then no there is no such graph.

Comment: $K_n$ has connectivity 2 only for $n=3$.  Recall that connectivity of 2 means that is the cardinality of the minimum disconnecting set.  While $K_n$ is 2-connected for $n\ge 2$, it only has connectivity 2 for $n=3$.